# Fastest way to convert raster to polygon using R

Tags: r, raster-conversion

I am trying to convert my raster file to vector using R. I tried to do it with ArcMap but it is taking more than expected time. RasterToVector is also not working because the file is too big. Can anyone suggest a better command in R?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Could you please detail the process you used to convert the data. Also, a detailed description of your raster data including file size, spatial resolution, band info, and bit depth would be helpful.

Comment: check the ``fasterize`` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasterize/vignettes/using-fasterize.html).

Comment: see spex::polygonize  (fasterize is the opposite)